# Installation of SQL Server Express LocalDB 2017

Tags: installation, sql-server-localdb

I want to install Microsoft SQL Server LocalDB 2017 on my system. I downloaded SQL Server Express Setup (about 5.1 MB). Then I opened it and chose 'Download Media' option and then chose LocalDB. Then it downloaded SqlLocalDB.msi setup (about 45.9 MB). I ran the setup and installed it on my computer. I don't know what to do next. Can someone help me, please?

Output of Running "SqlLocalDb info" command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqllocaldb info "MyInstance"
Name:               MyInstance
Version:            14.0.1000.169
Shared name:
Owner:              XXXXX
Auto-create:        No
State:              Stopped
Last start time:    05-11-2018 04:07:11 PM
Instance pipe name:
```

Answer (score 3):

LocalDB is a quirky flavor of SQL Server. In most cases, unless there's specific functionality in LocalDB that you need, I'd suggest running the "regular" Express Edition--as you can avoid quirks like the one you're running into. Additional details of differences are included in [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/edition-sql-server-best-development-work/).

LocalDB has an "automatic" instance that is tied to current user. To connect to that instance, you would use a connection string like `"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true"`.

You can also create an explicitly named instance using the `SQLLocalDB.exe` command line utility. Depending on your installed version, the path may vary (in this example, `130` is SQL Server 2016, but you would use `140` for 2017, etc):

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn"
C:\> SqlLocalDB.exe create MyLocalDB
C:\> SqlLocalDB.exe start MyLocalDB
```

The `SQLLocalDB info` command can be used at any time to determine the state of an instance, whether it is running or not:

```
C:\> SqlLocalDB.exe info MyLocalDB
```

Additional info on creating & connecting to a LocalDB instance can be found on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I could have used the regular Express Edition software. But since I want my server ready for small scale local development, I have opted for LocalDB. I just want it to practice my database concepts at the school level. So I do not want to spend excessive resources by runnig my server at full instances.